How to change default "and" in amsart title
I am writing an Spanish paper so I'd like to change "and" default conjuction for "y" in the command \maketitle in the class amsart.
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\author[Sagasta]{Práxedes Mateo Sagasta}%
\author[Canovas]{Antonio Cánovas del Castillo}%

\title{La Campana de Huesca}

\begin{document}
   \maketitle
\end{document}

Anyone knows how to change this?

Thanks in advance. Best regards!

Beware that the optional argument to \author should be an abbreviated version of the name for the page headings, not just a key: your 1 and 2 aren't abbreviations and on even numbered pages the heading would be “1 y 2”. There shouldn't be a space before the closing brace either.

You could redefine \@@and:
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@@and}{y}
\makeatother

\author[Sagasta]{Práxedes Mateo Sagasta}%
\author[Canovas]{Antonio Cánovas del Castillo}%

\title{La Campana de Huesca}

\begin{document}
   \maketitle
\end{document}

